# Display Distinct Dates Not Exist In Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sqlfiddle

I have a table called `maximo_products` and have a field called `product_date`.

I need to display all distinct dates which are not in in `maximo_products` table in `MON-YYYY` format 
between Jan-2014 and Dec-2014.

How can do this?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/13ef4/1) with table structure and records.

Sample output (dates which are not available in table)

```
MAR-2014
APR-2014
JUN-2014
JUL-2014    
SEP-2014
```

Comment: Not clear what do you want to receive.

Comment: @Avt In my table I have distinct dates for JAN,FEB,MAR,MAY,AUG etc. I would like to display distinct dates which doesn't exist in table.

Comment: Change your output sample. It contains `JUN` twice

Comment: @Avt Output sample has been edited, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the missing months, you need to generate all the months.  The following uses a simple formulation for getting 12 months.  It then uses `not in` to figure out which have no values:

```
with mons as (
      select rownum r, add_months('01-JAN-2014', rownum - 1) as mon
      from dual
      connect by rownum <= 12
     )
select *
from mons 
where not exists (select 1
                  from maximo_products mp
                  where to_char(mp.product_date, 'YYYY-MM') = 
                        to_char(mons.mon, 'YYYY-MM')
                 )
order by r;
```

EDIT:

You can move the definition of `mons` into a subquery:

```
select *
from (select rownum r, add_months('01-JAN-2014', rownum - 1) as mon
      from dual
      connect by rownum <= 12
     ) mons 
where not exists (select 1
                  from maximo_products mp
                  where to_char(mp.product_date, 'YYYY-MM') = 
                        to_char(mons.mon, 'YYYY-MM')
                 )
order by r;
```

Comment: Could this be possible to achieve without `with` clause?